Assign a value from an aws command to a field for further queries
I use the aws command list-objects and jq to return the number of certain files in a bucket:
aws s3api list-objects --bucket &S3_BUCKET# --prefix &S3_PREFIX# | jq length

I want to write this value to a variable number_of_elements
number_of_elements = aws sa3api ....

and use it for further processing:
if [ number_of_elements == 0]
then
      exit
else
    .....
fi

I use this programming in UC4 Automic to block a workflow if input files are missing. The aws command works. Unfortunately, the assignment of the variable does not work.
Greetings from a bash newbie
see description above

You need quotes around &S3_BUCKET# and &S3_PREFIX#.

Just an additional remark: There is an Automic S3 Agent for Amazon Cloud. We use it to up- and download and list files from buckets.

To assign the output of a command to a variable use
number_of_elements=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket &S3_BUCKET# --prefix &S3_PREFIX# | jq length)

